# How do I remove a handler from a loguru.logger when using pytest?

Tags: python, logging, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I wrote a `Thing` class that does logging using `loguru`. At the bottom of the class file I add a handler to the logger. This is what `thing.py` looks like.

```py
from loguru import logger


class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("Thing created")

    def __enter__(self):
        logger.info("Thing entered")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        logger.info("Thing exited")


logger.add("thing.log")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Thing() as thing:
        logger.info("In with block")
```

This works fine and it logs to thing.log as expected. What I would like to achieve is that it does *not* add the handler to thing.log when running tests.

This is my test file:

```py
import pytest
from loguru import logger
from thing import Thing


@pytest.fixture
def thing(mocker):
    mocker.patch("thing.logger", logger)
    with Thing() as thing:
        yield thing


def test_thing(thing, mocker):
    mocker.patch("thing.logger", logger)
    logger.info("In test")
    assert isinstance(thing, Thing)
```

Now this test passes, but the logs are still written to thing.log (instead to only stdout, which is the default in for a loguru.logger).

How do I make sure that it only logs to the basic `loguru.logger` when running pytest?

What I tried:

- Using monkeypatch instead of using mocker: `monkeypatch.setattr("thing.logger", logger)`
- Patching in only one place (either in the fixture or in the test function)
- Patching without replacement: `mocker.patch("thing.logger")` (so without a replacement logger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `logger.add("thing.log")` from `thing.py`!

You can either specify (as said in the [docs](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html)) that you want to log to `stdout`: `logger.add(sys.stdout)` or just leave it out because the default for `loguru.logger` is in fact `stdout`!

The example provided in their docs:

```
logger.add(sys.stdout, format="{time} - {level} - {message}", filter="sub.module")
```

**EDIT:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.add("thing.log")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Thing() as thing:
        #...
```

Now the logger will log to `thing.log` when the module is executed directly, but it will NOT add the file handler when the module is imported by another module (e.g. a test file).

Or you can use `logger.remove(0)` to stop logging when calling `thing(mocker)`!

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough. When I'm *not* running tests, I *do* want to log to thing.log (I edited my post).

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Let me change my answer!

Comment: Edited my reply accordingly @Lewistrick

Comment: Thanks! The last sentence might help me. Because when thing.Thing is imported from another place, it should also emit logs (so pytest is the exception here).

Comment: It did! I ended up using `logger.remove()` to remove all handlers. Don't even need to use mocking/monkeypatching any more :)